# Rsync fails to set the proper uids

Tags: linux, rsync

I try to rsync a folder from server A to server B:

```
rsync -aAXSHPr --numeric-ids --fake-super --delete --delete-after --delete-excluded -e "ssh -i key" root@1.2.3.4:/home/vmail/ /home/vmail/

rsync -avz --numeric-ids --fake-super --delete --delete-after --delete-excluded -e "ssh -i key" root@1.2.3.4:/home/vmail/ /home/vmail/
```

No matter how I try rsync does not set the vmail owner on certain files (leaves them owned by root). I don't interrupt the process, I know it should do it at the end.

The vmail user has the exact same UID on both servers.
I can of course chown the files after rsyncing.

What can go wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to be root I dont know why you are using `--fake-super`. You should try removing it.

I've never used the option, but reading the man page seems to suggest when using `--fake-super` you are also supposed to use `-M--fake-super` so it is applied at both ends.